# Map service in docker compose to host.docker.internal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I am preparing the docker-compose yml file based on a template. Which means sometimes all the services will run inside the composition and sometimes I'll want to exclude some of the services and run them locally.
So, I want to do something like this:

```
extra_hosts:
    - "<some_service_name>:host.docker.internal"
```

Unfortunately it complains that this is invalid.
I would really appreciate if someone could help.

- I'm using Docker desktop on macOS

Comment: Can you use environment variables to specify the dependency locations, rather than the hosts file?

Comment: This would require a bunch of code changes, so I would prefer not to.